# Cardinality of a collection of functions whose composition commutes

Tags: functional-analysis, commutative-algebra, cardinals, function-and-relation-composition

Consider a collection of functions $\mathcal F$ where (i) each individual element is a strictly increasing function from [0,1] to [0,1]; (ii) for any $f,g$ $f \le g$ or $f \ge g$ and $f\ne g$; and (iii) for any finite subcollection of functions $f_{1}\circ f_{2}\circ f_{3}\circ....\circ f_{n}=f_{\pi(1)}\circ f_{\pi(2)}\circ f_{\pi(3)}\circ....\circ f_{\pi(n)}$, where $\pi$ is permutation of the first $n$ natural numbers, that is any finite collection of functions satisfies the commutative property under composition. Can such a class of functions be uncountable?

Comment: What is the context for this question?  What have you tried?

Comment: I came across this result from Ritt where the class of polynomials that commute under composition is identified. I went down the rabbit hole trying to understand the nature of functions with possible discontinuities that can commute under composition. But failed to come up with anything beyond 2. My initial statement is likely sloppy even with the edit I made.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something from your question, but doesn't the family of functions of the form $x \mapsto ax$, for $a \in (0, 1]$, give an uncountable example?

Comment: Nope, that is correct. I will remove the question. TY